# ERROR: Unable to extract course id; - Udemy

Tags: python, video, download, youtube-dl

I tried to download a Udemy course, using `youtube-dl`, with the command below

```
C:\Users\victo> youtube-dl -u user@gmail.com -p password course_link
```

But, it returned

```
[udemy:course] Downloading login popup
[udemy:course] Logging in
[udemy:course] course: Downloading webpage
[udemy:course] 1622370: Downloading course curriculum
[download] Downloading playlist: 1622370
[udemy:course] playlist 1622370: Collected 10 video ids (downloading 10 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 10
[udemy] Downloading login popup
[udemy] 9850364: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to extract course id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

How to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the course URL you have provided whether it has /course in the URL provided.

```
Actual URL: https://www.udemy.com/course/zoho-creator-tutorial-series/learn/lecture
Input URL(should Be): https://www.udemy.com/zoho-creator-tutorial-series/learn/lecture
```

**Alternative Approach**

1. pip install youtube-dl(you can skip this as you have installed this)
2. install [cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg/related) extension in chrome
3. Login to Udemy and click on the extension to save the cookies
4. `youtube-dl --cookies <CookiesPath> -o "<BasePath>/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s – %(chapter)s/%(playlist_index)s – %(title)s.%(ext)s" "<CourseURL>"`

Whereas,

- CookiesPath   - The Location with the file name that cookies downloaded by cookies.txt.
- BasePath      - Output location where the downloaded videos will be preserved.
- CourseURL     - Udemy course URL. If the actual URL is https://www.udemy.com/course/zoho-creator-tutorial-series/learn/lecture then you should provide like https://www.udemy.com/zoho-creator-tutorial-series/learn/lecture (With /course in the URL).